# Can't sign user in using OAuth Office 365

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I've been stuck on this for 3 days now. I wish there are error messages or something that can tell me where to go.

1. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) tutorial on how to create a bot and authenticate users.
2. I used Azure v2 for authentication.
3. I registered my app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.
4. On azure, I went to my bot > settings > OAuth Connection Settings > Add setting > and filled out the fields for office 365 and saved it.
5. I clicked "Test connection" and I see my authentication token it retrieved.
6. I copied [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-oauth/app.js) and set the connection name of the login setting I made in step 4.
7. I run the bot locally and see [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOyg5.png).
8. I click that sign in button. Nothing happens. No error message in console log either.
9. I type another message to the bot and see [this response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo3iI.png).

I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#to-create-an-azure-ad-v2-application to create an aad v2 application and configure your bot service correctly?

Please try to use 'Azure Active Directory v2' instead of 'office 365'.

And besides, for you 9th issue, you can simply add a sentence under the `signOutUser` function like:

```
connector.signOutUser(session.message.address, connectionName, (err, result) => {
            if (!err) {
                session.send('You are signed out.');
                session.userData.activeSignIn = false;
            } else {
                session.send('There was a problem signing you out.');
            }
        });
```

And type `signout` before you wanting to re-signin to force you are signout in session.